# when hiranyaksha dipped earth in water (ocean) how to know that ocean existed out of ocean. actually out of earth there is no ocean

Tags: vishnu

Hiranyaksha how can he hide earth in ocean, when there is no water out of earth. in galaxy there is no water. how can he hide earth in ocean?

Comment: "in galaxy there is no water. how can he hide earth in ocean?" [Scientific questions are not endorsed here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/143/277).

Comment: @SK Or the other possibility is that the story is true.  That would explain how a story too strange for anyone to come up with it would come about.

Comment: thats a great argument - this story is so absurd it has to be true.

Comment: @SK it was Varaaha, wild boar. Not a pig. Moreover, it is an episode of great wondrous pastime of Narayana.

Comment: _"there is no water outside Earth"_ How can you say that. Have you and scientists has searched whole infinite spance out of Earth? Space is endless. And one can't comment about endless. Besides, have you forgot Sheer Sagar? Sheer Sagar is not on Earth.